# How to deploy JSF v1.2 apps to WebSphere v9.0 (Full and Liberty)?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, jsf-1.2

WebSphere v9.0.0.2 full profile does not provide anymore `JSF v1.2` support it seems

Q: What about "legacy" apps that are written in `JSF v1.2` + `facelets` (facelets was not part of the `JSF` standard at this time), can they be deployed to WAS v9.0 or are we stuck to WAS v8.5.5?

I didn't find a way in the doc to deploy a JSF v1.2 app on WAS v9.0 and my many tries were unsuccessful (problems with jar `jsf-facelets.jar` amongst other problems)

Q: Is there a workaround for deploying such apps on WAS v9.0?

We need also to deploy sucha apps on `Liberty v16.0.0.4`...

Answer (score -2):

The best option will be to migrate your application to support JSF 2.2, which shouldn't be terribly difficult.  There is some IBM documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/java-server-faces-migration/) for migrating your application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0.  Since your application already uses Facelets, however, you should be able to migrate your app via configuration changes; the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532870/3864977) will probably be more helpful.

It is also possible to configure WebSphere to use a third party JSF provider - in that case, you could provide your own version of JSF 1.2 for your application.  Documentation for that is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf22.html)

Instructions for providing a custom JSF implementation:

```
Add the third-party listener to the web.xml file.
Add the third-party JSF implementation Java™ archive (JAR) files and its required dependant JAR files to the application as an isolated shared library and associate it with your application:
    Move the JSF JAR files and all third-party libraries referenced by the JSF JAR files and UI component plug-ins (for example, PrimeFaces) to a directory outside of the application.
    Create the isolated shared library. See topic Creating shared libraries for information about how to create the shared library.
    Ensure that the classloader is set to PARENT_FIRST, the default value. To view the current configuration in the administrative console panel, click Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > application_name > Class loading and update detection.
```

Comment: This would be "terribly difficult"...We use JSF 1.2+ facelets-pre-jsf2.0+richfaces v3 which is not compatbaile with JSF 2.x+. Our newer apps use JSF 2.2 + primefaces.. Also the link you gave explain how to deploy a custom JSF 2.x implementation, in WAS v9.0 not to deploy a custom jSF 1.2 implementation

Comment: The doc I linked to for deploying a custom implementation says nothing about being restricted to JSF 2.x; deploying JSF 1.2 should work fine.  I'll update the answer with those steps.